# Element re-directing to other element in Robot Framework

Tags: html, angularjs, robotframework

I'm developing a Robot Framework test that, effectively, clicks two elements (that work fine) and then confirms that you want to do something in a dialog box that pops up within the HTML (so, not an alert). Everything works fine, up until the dialog box. The box contains a total of two buttons. The buttons have the `<button>` tag name in HTML but were created using Angular JS, and have the text "Yes" and "No". I want to click the one labeled "Yes". Every locator method I know of to select the button labeled "Yes" clicks the one labeled "No", while everything I do to click "No" works just fine.

I can't post the HTML itself (proprietary) or my exact Robot Framework code and variables (written specifically for the proprietary site, they mention parts of the site explicitly so I'd prefer to err on the side of "not getting fired/sued"). The above information is generic enough that, thankfully, it could apply to almost any site that doesn't use standard pop-up messages and is written in Angular JS, so I can give that out.

However, here is a generalized version of my Robot Framework code that's having the trouble.

```
Click Element   ${item}
Sleep           1s
Click Element   ${edit_button}
Sleep           1s
Click Element   ${yes_button}
```

I have tried using the xpath (generalized and full), the dom in the form of dom=document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0] (the location as found in the browser console), changing it to `Click Button    Yes`, and finding it by the text "Yes" using the following (totally generic and so shareable) keyword:

```
Click Element by Text
    #   EXAMPLE USAGE
    #   Click Element by Text   "text on the element"   id="midlevellocationoftext"     button
    #   NOTE:   Does not account for extra spaces at the beginning or end, text must be exact
    #   NOTE:   Allows for injections on purpose to allow user to be more exact with their location
    [Arguments]     ${text}     ${location}=*   ${elementtype}=*
    Click Element   xpath=//*[@${location}]//${elementtype}[text()=${text}]
```

It's totally possible that the problem is not with my code but rather the HTML/AngularJS, but in manual testing, the element remains clickable, and so I must find a way to click it. Just to eliminate the usual possibilities, it does not have an id, the class is ungodly levels of long and shared between the two buttons (except for the on-click actions "check" and "close"), and the location of the box by pixel changes from screen size to screen size and won't be running on my screen size.

To cover other potential questions: I'm aware that it does not follow the standard practices for accessible HTML; I have ExtendedSelenium2Library, Collections, Operating System, and two custom libraries loaded (neither of which is in use); I'm working in Google Chrome; I'm not the developer; and the developer is too busy working on other parts of the site with a tight deadline to add ids because the test developer can't click a single button.

So, my questions to the community: what haven't I tried, what could I try, and why won't the tried-and-true solutions work? If you need more specific information, I'll provide whatever I can. If you can somehow recognize this as a bug in the Angular JS or HTML and somehow know potential fixes, awesome. Let me know so I can let the developer know.

Comment: To avoid telling readers that you can't show them the code you're working on, could you create an [mcve]? You may find that when building up the HTML document in your test case, you find out yourself what is causing the problem.

Comment: I did put that in there in the first section. I'm not writing the HTML or Angular JS, as stated above. I'm writing the Robot Framework only, the reason for the HTML and Angular JS tags is because the problem might be in one of those two parts of the site I'm writing against or in my interaction with them, so the example of the code that is failing is the first block of code.

Comment: My apologies, @halfer. I did not understand exactly what you meant. The answer is no, I cannot, as I'm not sure what part of the AngularJS/HTML is causing this to happen. I was hoping someone had some experience with this phenomena before and could suggest parts of the HTML (not AngularJS, I don't have access to that code) to give the minimal, complete, and verifiable example of.